# How to create a probabilistic ranking across points from different sets of data?

Tags: normal-distribution, ranking

I'm trying to do this project that creates a sort of "universal score" across a set of games - if I play a game that gives me a certain score, and I have a friend who plays a different game and has a certain score in that game, how can I tell whether I am higher or lower ranked than him without playing his game?

What I was thinking of doing was assuming the game scores were under a standard normal distribution, and so the top 1% of one game would be equal in skill to the top 1% in another game, the top 2% would be equal, and so on. Is this correct, or am I missing something that would make it a more accurate ranking system?

EDIT: I will have distributions of score data for all the games.

Comment: Do you actually have distributions of score data? Or just percentiles for yourself and your friend? Score distributions often don't follow normal distributions; take rep score here for instance.

Comment: I do, in fact, have distributions for the scores in each game - not just me and my friend.

Comment: Good! That helps. You won't have to (and probably shouldn't want to) assume a normal distribution. Depending on how scores are actually distributed (or whatever else you know about the scoring systems, some of which might be more useful), the differences in skill between certain percentile ranges might not be as meaningful as other differences. (E.g., if any large bonuses are unlocked after long investments of grinding that don't involve much learning.)